# Во второй половине 1860-х/1860 годов

Tags: наращение

Как правильно?

> Сочинения ученого оценили по достоинству только после его смерти, во второй половине 1860-х/1860 годов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идëт о десятке или десятках лет, наращение ставится всегда:

*Сочинения ученого оценили по достоинству только после его смерти, во второй половине 1860-х годов*.

Смотрите примеры из [«Грамоты.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%A5%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2), там везде стоят наращения.